# Error when compiling and installing php7.4 under centos7_aarch64

Tags: php, makefile, cmake, raspberry-pi, make-install

```
/www/server/php/74/src/ext/standard/browscap.c -o ext/standard/browscap.lo 
In file included from /www/server/php/74/src/Zend/zend.h:356:0,
                 from /www/server/php/74/src/main/php.h:33,
                 from /www/server/php/74/src/ext/standard/array.c:24:
/www/server/php/74/src/ext/standard/array.c: In function ‘zif_array_sum’:
/www/server/php/74/src/Zend/zend_operators.h:674:2: error: invalid 'asm': invalid operand prefix '%c'
  __asm__ goto(
  ^
make: *** [ext/standard/array.lo] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/bin/sh /www/server/php/74/src/libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps --mode=link cc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/www/server/php/74/src/include -I/www/server/php/74/src/main -I/www/server/php/74/src -I/www/server/php/74/src/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libpng15 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/www/server/php/74/src/ext/mbstring/libmbfl -I/www/server/php/74/src/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl -I/www/server/php/74/src/TSRM -I/www/server/php/74/src/Zend    -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/openssl/include -I/usr/local/curl/include -fvisibility=hidden -Wall -Wno-strict-aliasing -DZEND_SIGNALS     -o ext/opcache/opcache.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath /www/server/php/74/src/modules  ext/opcache/ZendAccelerator.lo ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_blacklist.lo ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_debug.lo ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_hash.lo ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_module.lo ext/opcache/zend_persist.lo ext/opcache/zend_persist_calc.lo ext/opcache/zend_file_cache.lo ext/opcache/zend_shared_alloc.lo ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_util_funcs.lo ext/opcache/shared_alloc_shm.lo ext/opcache/shared_alloc_mmap.lo ext/opcache/shared_alloc_posix.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_optimizer.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass1_5.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass2.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass3.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/optimize_func_calls.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/block_pass.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/optimize_temp_vars_5.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/nop_removal.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/compact_literals.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_cfg.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_dfg.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/dfa_pass.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_ssa.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_inference.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_func_info.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_call_graph.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/sccp.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/scdf.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/dce.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/escape_analysis.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/compact_vars.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_dump.lo -lrt
/bin/sh /www/server/php/74/src/libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps --mode=install cp ext/opcache/opcache.la /www/server/php/74/src/modules
/bin/sh /www/server/php/74/src/libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps --mode=compile cc -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -Iext/standard/ -I/www/server/php/74/src/ext/standard/ -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/www/server/php/74/src/include -I/www/server/php/74/src/main -I/www/server/php/74/src -I/www/server/php/74/src/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libpng15 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/www/server/php/74/src/ext/mbstring/libmbfl -I/www/server/php/74/src/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl -I/www/server/php/74/src/TSRM -I/www/server/php/74/src/Zend    -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/openssl/include -I/usr/local/curl/include -fvisibility=hidden -Wall -Wno-strict-aliasing -DZEND_SIGNALS   -c /www/server/php/74/src/ext/standard/array.c -o ext/standard/array.lo 
In file included from /www/server/php/74/src/Zend/zend.h:356:0,
                 from /www/server/php/74/src/main/php.h:33,
                 from /www/server/php/74/src/ext/standard/array.c:24:
/www/server/php/74/src/ext/standard/array.c: In function ‘zif_array_sum’:
/www/server/php/74/src/Zend/zend_operators.h:674:2: error: invalid 'asm': invalid operand prefix '%c'
  __asm__ goto(
  ^
make: *** [ext/standard/array.lo] Error 1
========================================================
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (AltArch)
Bit:64 Mem:3796M Core:4 gcc:4.8.5 cmake:3.19.4
Linux 5.4.72-v8.1.el7 aarch64
```

The above error occurred when I tried to make test, and it can be compiled under php7.3, what should I do?

Comment: I don't think you can easily fix that. It's an inline assembly code and the assembler language and binding will be different for each platform/processor. Probably you would need to find out what was that inline supposed to do and find and code equivalent instructions for aarch64.

Comment: oh,so bad,Thank you reply.